# How to keep the data consistent between redis cache and mysql?

Tags: python, mysql, django, redis

When I updated the data of mysql dabatase, the redis cache was not updated in time. What should I do to make mysql data change, redis can also clear the old cache in time?

Comment: Welcome, I think your question needs more elaboration. Are you using a third party package to cache on redis? or are you creating the cache yourself?

Comment: add some more description.

Comment: Are you facing the case of cache invalidation? You could look into "expire" in Redis. You could choose an appropriate time to invalidate the Redis cache and read again from MySQL. If your data changes quite rapidly, it is better to not cache it at all.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend use some MySQL CDC(change data capture) tools, capture the data change event and evict the relational redis key.
https://github.com/wushujames/mysql-cdc-projects/wiki

(It's not a strong consistent, but is a very simple way to do)